# Trying to predict in R

Tags: r, random

I created a data set using a random row generator:

```
training_data <- fulldata[sample(nrow(fulldata),100,]
```

I am under the impression that I can create a second data set of the rest of the data ... `rest_data <- fulldata[-training_data]` is the code I jotted down in my notes but I am getting

> "Error in '[.default'(fulldata, -training_data) :

What part of my code is incorrect?

Comment: training_data <- fulldata[sample(nrow(fulldata),100),] the missing ) was a typo, it is in my code. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `fulldata`is a dataframe you need a comma in the subscript to indicate that you want the rows of the data frame (i.e. `fulldata[rows,columns]`). But the indices of the new dataframe `training_data` will be numbered `1:100`so you need a different sort of indicator that corresponds between `training_data`and `fulldata` to show which rows of `fulldata` should not be included. What you might do is use the rownames, something like:

```
rest_data<-fulldata[-which(rownames(fulldata)%in%rownames(training_data)),]
```

which should tell R to remove the rownames of `fulldata` that occur in `training_data`. If you have something like an `ID` variable that is unique to each row you could also use this

```
rest_data<-fulldata[-which(fulldata$ID%in%training_data$ID),]
```